# How do you get the sigil of malice recipe?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I understand that there's a vendor with the recipe for the "[Sigil of Malice](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil_of_Malice)" located in the crown pavilion, but as a player who was not able to access the crown pavilion during that event last year, how can you access the vendor and/or recipe?

Comment: The Crown Pavilion is returning next week on the 20th of May during the [Festival of Four Winds](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/prepare-for-the-festival-of-the-four-winds/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sigil of Malice recipe is now only obtainable through one method. This method is by buying it off the Trading Post. The vendor that sold this recipe is now not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get it any more... maybe try buy from tp (can't remember if it was account bound)?

Comment: Yes, it's available on the TP (http://www.gw2spidy.com/search/Sigil%20of%20Malice?recipes=0) Looking at the wiki page for the recipe you can't aquire it from events any more, as both Crown Pavilion and Scarlet are finished.